# Showing Sylow $p$-subgroup is an elementary abelian $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Suppose $0<a<p$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Then how can I show that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{ap}$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group?

EDIT: I showed that the order of Sylow $p$-subgroups are $p^a$. Now if I want these  Sylow $p$-subgroups to be elementary abelian, then all of their nonidentity elements should have order $p$. Elements of order $p$ in $S_{ap}$ look like either a $p$-cycle $(1 2 ... p)$ or a product of disjoint $p$-cycles. Now the group generated by $\langle (1 2 ...p) \rangle $ has order $p$. To get a group of order $p^a$, I believe I should take the direct product of $a$-many different subgroups each of which is generated by a single $p$-cycle, and all these generators are different. (Is this correct?..) However, would that even be a subgroup of $S_{ap}$? Or is that group would be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{ap}$?

Comment: Just by exhibiting one, I think.

Comment: Also, "odd" is not necessary.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The fact that I didn’t include details about what I’ve tried so far doesn’t mean I haven’t put in hours to do it.

Comment: @abeliangrape What Shaun posted is actually standard text. If you've tried this already, then do tell us what you've got so far, it'll make it easier for us to help you. Otherwise, your question might get closed.

Comment: @verret I have edited the original post with details of what I have thought so far. And yes, odd is not necessary, but when $p$ is even we know that the only pair of $(a, p)$ is $(1, 2)$, which is a trivial case. That's why the examiner must have omitted it on purpose.

Comment: @Shaun  I have edited the original post with details of what I have thought so far.

Comment: @YCor Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

$S_{ap}$ contains a product of $a$ cyclic groups of order $p$. In fact a set of $ap$ elements is a disjoint union of $a$ sets of $p$ elements. Therefore it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $S_p^a$, and as a sub-subgroup a product of product of $a$ cyclic groups of order $p$.

Comment: Why is the first sentence in your answer correct?

Comment: The explanation is in the second and third sentences...

Comment: I think I don't understand how the second sentence implies the third. Why "therefore"?

Comment: If you have a set X which is the disjoint union of two sets A, B then the group of permutations of X contains the product of the group of permutations of A and that of B. Agree ?

Comment: This is something I have not heard before. Are you saying $S_{5}$ contains $S_{2} \times S_{3}$? Why is that -- by Cayley's Theorem?

Comment: $S_5$ is the permutation group of 5 objects, named say $(a,b, 1,2,3)$. You think that $S_2$ is permuting $a,b$ and $S_3$ permuting $1,2,3$.

Comment: Yes but is Cayley’s thm idea correct?

Comment: No, the Cayley's theorem idea is not the key idea. The key idea is the explicit description of how $S_5$ contains $S_2\times S_3$ given in @Thomas' last comment. You can see the subgroup of $S_5$ that acts separately on $\{a,b\}$ and on $\{1,2,3\}$ as being $S_2\times S_3$, where the first factor is the action on $\{a,b\}$ and the second factor is the action on $\{1,2,3\}$.